# How do you save the configuration of a Cisco switch?

Tags: cisco

I have a Cisco 2960s switch with 24-port 10/100/1000 Ethernet Switch with PoE, and I have set it up correctly (I think). I can't work out how to save the setting I have made because every time I unplug the device it resets to the factory settings.

Comment: Seriously? "Copy run start".

Answer (score 5):

Been a while since I touched a Cisco box, but the last time I looked, it was just:

```
copy running-config startup-config
```

Answer (score 0):

Or a even shorter command...

```
Router# wr
```

For more basic commands, please check: 
http://boubakr92.wordpress.com/2013/09/16/ccna-cheat-sheet-part-1/